# Promise hangs even though it is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestjs

I am using `request-promise` module to check whether site is working with proxy or not. I am trying to find the proxies which is fast enough to answer in 5 seconds. Therefore I only add object if request doesn't timeout in 5 seconds.

For some proxies, even though promise resolves, node script hangs for a while. I can't find the reason of this delay. I see that it prints `Done` but it hangs. After 1 minute 10 seconds later, script exits. Is this hang due to my code, or operating system issue for open sockets etc?

```
const rp =  require('request-promise');
const testProxies = [
    {
       "ipAddress": "80.241.219.83",
       "port": 3128,
    },
    {
        "ipAddress": "45.55.27.246",
        "port": 80
    },
    {
        "ipAddress": "144.217.197.71",
        "port": 8080,
    },
    {
        "ipAddress": "104.131.168.255",
        "port": 80,
    },
    ];

function CheckSites(sitesArray,site) {
    let ps = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sitesArray.length; i++) {
        let proxy = sitesArray[i];

        let ops = {
            method: 'GET',
            resolveWithFullResponse: true,
            proxy: 'http://' + proxy.ipAddress + ':' + proxy.port,
            uri:site,
        };
        let resp =  rp.get(ops);
        ps.push(resp);
    }
    return Promise.all(ps.map(function (p) {
        p.time =  Date.now();
        return p
            .then(function (a) {
                return {'header':a.headers,'time':Date.now() - p.time};
            })
            .timeout(5000)
            .catch(function (e) {
                return {};
            })
    }))
}
CheckSites(testProxies,'https://www.example.com').then(function (object) {
    console.log('Done!');
    console.log(object);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Exception: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For your use case I suggest you to use the [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) it behaves as `Promise.all` but you get the callback as soon as the fastest proxy responds.

I've investigated more on the bug, and it seems to be [a `request` module issue](https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/50), when you use timeout, they just don't close the connection and it's in hang-up state

Comment: I am getting `Done! `on console. It means all promises are resolved. Also even with `Promise.race()` it still hangs for a while then script exits

Comment: @Meanteacher I updated my answer seems to be request module bug, on timeout https://github.com/request/request/issues/1676 they do not close the connection.

Comment: I checked your link which links to another issue. However, that user says it was an error on his code. I still can't understand the reason. Thanks anyway.